# UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn not working inside coordinated animation

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation, tvos

I am in the middle of developing a tvOS application.

In my application I have a `UICollectionView`. On focus I am using a coordinated animation. Inside that animation I have this code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.bg.image = finalImage
                    self.bg.alpha = 1.0
                    }, completion: nil)
```

But it seems like its not using the `curveEaseIn` animation option.

Its changing the alpha bluntly, which is odd. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Placing an animation block inside another animation block is not going yield good results.

Answer (score 0):

What is the desired effect? Are you trying to cross fade `bg.image` with a new image? Have you tried changing the duration to something higher, for example `10.0`, to see if the animation is perhaps happening too fast?

Here's an example of what you may be looking for:

```
let myImageView = UIImageView()
let myFinalImage = UIImage(named:"FinalImage.png")

// Animate alpha
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    print("alpha animation started")
    myImageView.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (finished) in
        print("alpha animation finished")
}

// Animate change of image
UIView.transitionWithView(myImageView, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    print("cross dissolve animation started")
    myImageView.image = myFinalImage
    }) { (finished) in
        print("cross dissolve animation finished")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Forgot to post the answer.

I did animating the imageview in the completion of the coordinated animation like this

```
   self.bg.alpha = 0.0
   coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ //code for coordinated animation}, completion: { _ in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.bg.image = self.finalImage
                    self.bg.alpha = 1.0
                    }, completion: nil)})
```

Comment: You can replace `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn` with just `.CurveEaseIn`.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 4 or Swift 5 use: **.curveEaseIn**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
              ...
        }) { (finished) in
             ...
        }
```

Comment: Thats the exact same thing as doing UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn

Comment: The c is lowercase remove "UIViewAnimationOptions"